# Memory efficient way to store boolean information for around 10000 variables with dynamic allocation

Tags: c++, c, memory-management

I need to store boolean information for around 10000 variables. First I thought of using a bool array arr[10000] but it takes 40000 bytes. But I need to store this information in a memory efficient way. Maybe using bit manipulation? Also another thing that I need to store it globally and allocate it dynamically also. Can you please help me with this?

Comment: 4000 Bytes for 10000 bools means an average of 2.5 bools per byte, while I'd have expected either 1 or 8. What compiler and architecture are you using?

Comment: @DenisErmolin oh sorry yes size of bool is 1 byte..

Comment: Why should this ever be a problem? 40k is nothing on modern computers. Are you on a platform that is particularly constraint?

Comment: @DenisErmolin no in c you can not alloc/dealloc 1 bit storage.. google about this you will get more info

Comment: @JensGustedt yes i am working on memory constraint platform

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could do:

```
vals = new char[(len+7)/8];
// To access
vals[i/8] & 1 << (i % 8)
// To set
vals[i/8] |= 1 << (i % 8);
// To clear
vals[i/8] &= ~(char)(1 << (i % 8));
```

Though to be the fastest, you should use whatever the word size is sized chunks. So on a 32-bit computer:

```
vals = new uint32_t[(len+31)/32];
// To access
vals[i/32] & 1 << (i % 32)
// To set
vals[i/32] |= 1 << (i % 32);
// To clear
vals[i/32] &= ~(uint32_t)(1 << (i % 32));
```

Comment: B the OP asked about *memory efficiency* and using, say, 64 bit chunks for 4000 won't be the most memory efficient ;-)

Comment: if i use 16 bit integer then the statement should be 
vals = new uint32_t[(len+15)/16]; right?

Comment: @user1660982 basically, only uint16_t instead of uint32_t.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin On a 32-bit machine 4000 would fit with no waste. On a 64-bit machine (i.e. using 64-bit ints) you'd waste 4 bytes on top of the 500 required bytes. Probably not going to make a big diff, but I did change my language :P

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker No, it's a good point, I meant to say fastest, not most efficient (since it's not most efficient by his definition).

Comment: @CrazyCasta hey can you please explain why this typecast with uint32_t is done in the last line (to clear)?

Comment: @user1660982 That's just a cast, not a typecast (typecast is a different concept). The cast might not actually be needed. It's to assure that the value of 1 shifted to the left is of the correct size so that after ~ the only bit that won't be set is the 1 shifted to the left. This would probably be the most useful if int is smaller than what you are casting to (though you might need to cast up 1 before you shift it in that case).

Answer (score 3):

In C++ you have the options of `std::bitset<10000>` to store inidividual bits with a fixed size, or `std::vector<bool>` if you need the size to change dynamically. Both of these will use a single bit per value.

There is not much need to do the bit-fiddling by hand.

Comment: Sorry, overlooked the part where you also recommended std::vector<bool> before I wrote my answer. Great answer, there is really no need to do any bit fiddeling by hand!

Answer (score 1):

Clearly, about the most efficient way is to store one value a bit. Wich will take 8 times less memory.

Comment: what should i use.. i think a 16 bit integer will be fine?

Comment: Whatever pleases you. 16 bit integer is fine.

Comment: 8bit or 16bit is the most memory efficient way to go 10000 is exactly divisible by 8 and 16. In case of 32 bit you will waste 16 bits

Answer (score 1):

10000 is a very small number, current computers have several Gb of memory available. If you use a "int" type per boolean variable, that only accounts for 40kB which is tiny. Make it a `int arr[N]` first, then test and make measurements of performance before optimizing any further.

Going from a `int` per boolean variable to a bit packed format will make you use less memory, but everything will be slower since you have to pack and unpack the data from the compressed format. You gain memory but it is a trade-off and this sounds like a premature optimization that is unnecessary to me.

You can also use something like [RLE compression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding) or [BDDs](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binary_decision_diagram), they are more efficient but more complex to implement and again a different runtime/memory trade-off.

Answer (score 0):

I would make an array of bit fields as shown below. Thats 10000 exactly... for dynamic allocation just make BoolBytes a pointer, use malloc and bob's your uncle.

```
typedef struct
    {
    unsigned b0     :1;
    unsigned b1     :1;
    unsigned b2     :1;
    unsigned b3     :1;
    unsigned b4     :1;
    unsigned b5     :1;
    unsigned b6     :1;
    unsigned b7     :1;
    }BitField;

BitField BoolBytes[1250]; // The number of bools is OVER NINE-THOUSAAAAAAAND!
```

The other "efficiency" thing is asking whether 8 times lower memory is better than the added time to perform the address calculation of 10000 bools in memory. Not much of an overhead but this would be slightly slower than an array of bools.

Answer (score 0):

Using `std::vector<bool>` should be the easiest way. You can just use the well-known vector interface (which comes with dynamic allocation, e.g., by using `push_back` to add items to it) while all stl implementations I know (I'm not sure if it is also required by definition) use a template specialization for bool vectors and implement it as 1bit per value.

Note that the dynamic reallocation (you don't have to care about it, it's all done by the vector class) will allow constant amortized time for insertions, but may have a memory overhead (of some fraction of the actual number of bits) to allow this. In particular, whenever needed, a resizes will extend / shrink the allocated memory by a fraction of the current length.

While this is not in minimum rqeuired memory to store your information at every time, I would still condier it a memory efficient way.